# Best way to compute the transition matrix e^At - Octave

Tags: matlab, matrix, controls, octave, transition

I want to compute the state transition matrix in GNU Octave. But there are several ways to compute the state transition matrix.

Some ways are hard, some are easier. The best way is the numberical method to compute the state transition matrix.

Can you show me your best way to compute the state transition matrix by using GNU Octave with symbolic package?

Thank you!

Comment: Almost always, it's best not to do it yourself and trust the library: [`@sym/expm`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/symbolic/function/@sym/expm.html)

Comment: Thank you! You solved the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to find the transition matrix e^At is to use the command

```
expm(A*t)
```

Where `A` is a matrix and `h` is a scalar.